# escaping single quotes in python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

It seems like a typical issue in programming, but i didn't find nothing usefull in google.
This is the code:

```
file=open('list.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
        %s(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
        entry TEXT NOT NULL)" % line)
    file.close()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

And this is the error when I try to create a table with single quotes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 104, in <module>
    entry TEXT NOT NULL)" % line)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Hi 'Buddy!(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,         entry ' at line 1")
```

MySQLdb.escape_string(line) dont fix it by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing that and I think I should suggest re-thinking your schema, but you can escape a table name with backticks `` ` ``.

```
# notice the `'s surrounding %s
for line in file:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
    `%s`(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \
    entry TEXT NOT NULL)" % line)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot :) Now i just get errors with entries ended with a blank space but i hope it won't be hard to fix

Comment: Look at Python's `strip` method.

Answer (score 1):

afaik ([see MySQL 5.0 Reference here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)) you aren't allowed to have single quotes in a table name:

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> ```
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> ```

Comment: No. This is true for unquoted identifiers only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%s'(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, entry TEXT NOT NULL)" % line)
```

Comment: `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''Hey 'Buddy!'(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,         entry ' at line 1")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using % formatting to put in the value, pass in your statement to `cursor.execute()` with `%s` still in it for each value you need to replace, and a list or tuple of all replacement values as your second argument, for example:

```
stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, entry TEXT NOT NULL)"
value_list = [line]
cursor.execute(stmt, value_list)
```

This will perform all of the necessary escaping for you because it will turn your string into a valid SQL literal.  This comes straight from the [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), here is the relevant example:

> To perform a query, you first need a cursor, and then you can execute queries on it:
>
> ```
> c=db.cursor()
> max_price=5
> c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
>           WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
> ```
>
> In this example, max_price=5 Why, then, use %s in the string? Because MySQLdb will convert it to a SQL literal value, which is the string '5'. When it's finished, the query will actually say, "...WHERE price < 5".

Comment: hmm.. weird, now i see the error with escaped values `_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\\'Hey \\'Buddy!'(id INT(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,         entry' at line 1")`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're trying to make table names programmatically like this, you'll be happier using a different schema.  I would suggest making one table like this, with an additional column that will contain the string you are now using for the table name.